# Is there any benefit to put rel='nofollow' on mailto links?

Tags: links, googlebot, nofollow, mailto

Since bots have a fixed budget to spend to crawl websites on a regular basis, does it makes sense to mark `mailto` links with `rel='nofollow'` to make sure them don't spend time on these (especially if these are present on every page)?

Example:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@mycompany.com" rel="nofollow">Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so. Site crawlers don't go inside mailto hrefs.

Answer (score 0):

`rel='nofollow'` is useful when you don't trust links because you can't control them for example.

Why wouldn't you trust your `mailto` links? There is no reason and that's why the answer of your question is no.

Comment: Google does mention you can use rel='nofollow' for Crawl prioritization on links you don't need Google to follow, its not simply links you do not trust: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en